# How to integrate expandable list view inside navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, expandablelistview

I created a project for my expandable list view. Also, in my other main project, I created a navigation drawer. Everything works fine as it is own. Unfortunately, I want to show this expandable list view inside my navigation drawer and I don't know where to start. I feel like there should be minor additions (already have adapter and stuff) but seriously I have no idea about how to implement the layout inside the drawer. I searched about this topic and all examples and answers are not so clear to me.

Can you please point me to the right direction?

Comment: I don't think there is any difference in implementing expandable listview with/without navigation drawer

Comment: to make expandable list view appear and disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by adding `ExpandableListView` in `NavigationDrawer` like below:

You can create it using custom ListView.

See the code below activity_navigation_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/navigationmenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="192dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white">
        </ExpandableListView>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And Simply create adapter for it and use it like a normal `ExpandableListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom Layout to use custom navigation view as given below in (layout_nav_bar.xml):-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_white"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/nav_header"
        layout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:groupIndicator="@null" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Add this to your DrawerLayout

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        layout="@layout/layout_nav_bar"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```